# Подскажите команду для вывода количества операций цикла сортировки пузырьком

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    int digitals[10]; // объявили массив на 10 ячеек

    cout << "Введите 10 чисел для заполнения массива: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cin >> digitals[i]; // "читаем" элементы в массив
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (digitals[j] > digitals[j + 1]) {
                int b = digitals[j]; // создали дополнительную переменную
                digitals[j] = digitals[j + 1]; // меняем местами
                digitals[j + 1] = b; // значения элементов
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Массив в отсортированном виде: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << digitals[i] << " "; // выводим элементы массива
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Сделайте переменную `count`, а внутри двойного цикла, когда происходит обмен, увеличивайте `count` на единицу. Потом выводите её.

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите строки с комментарием

```
 // <--
```

в вашем коде:

```
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    int howmany = 0; // <-- Счетчик

    int digitals[10]; // объявили массив на 10 ячеек

    cout << "Введите 10 чисел для заполнения массива: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cin >> digitals[i]; // "читаем" элементы в массив
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (digitals[j] > digitals[j + 1]) {
                int b = digitals[j]; // создали дополнительную переменную
                digitals[j] = digitals[j + 1]; // меняем местами
                digitals[j + 1] = b; // значения элементов
                howmany++; // <-- Увеличиваем счетчик
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Массив в отсортированном виде: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << digitals[i] << " "; // выводим элементы массива
    }

    cout << "\n\nКоличество обменов: " << howmany << endl; // <-- Вывод результата
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```